# php post to use JSON_ENCODE

Tags: php, json, post, encode

I am trying to create the back-end for my app which has to allow emoticons to be send. With a form and `php POST`it gets send to a file which sends a notification with the emoticon (and optional text).
However if i use `$_POST` it will not be be encoded and just send as smiley, which will not be accepted by the devices (apple converts it?)

My Code:

```
$message = $_POST['message']; // contains only -> 
$test = "";
echo json_encode($test); //output = "\ud83d\ude07" AS it should be
echo json_encode(strval($message)); //outputs  which is false.
```

If i use `$_GET['message']` and change my other scripts it will work (used test file to check).
However having security in mind (browser history and such) i want to use `$_POST`.

how can i make this happen?

-- FORM as requested.
Please not that this is all i need So far.
]

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head<
    <body>

        <form action="./simplepush.php" method="post"> 
            Message   : <input type="text" name="message" /><br /> 
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /> 

        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Not using any headers (or specifying)

Comment: I have desired value also on POST (tested on chrome and safari /OSX). Can you show yr form and HTML header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to force the form to encode the post data as UTF8?

```
<form method="post" action="some/url" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Such an easy answer. How could i not have thought of that. =\.. thank you!